# Как переместить файл в php?!

Tags: файлы, php

Здравствуйте.
Есть файл, который генерируется библиотекой.

Он имеет путь

```
$filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'qr.png';
```

Как его переместить в другую папку?
К примеру, в /test/qr.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел, rename()